# dnsmasq conditional forwarding based on domain

Tags: dnsmasq

The desired result is that i need dnsmasq to forward queries it received based on the hostname it needs to resolve.

- DNS is the only function required. No dhcp, tftp, etc.
- 192.168.1.2 is the machine that is serving dnsmasq
- 192.168.1.7 is the machine that is querying dnsmask.
- It is not relevant or required to make the server at 192.168.1.2 follow these restrictions.

  For example, on 192.168.1.7 i type:

  nslookup something.mydomain.local

It should forward to a dns server of 10.0.1.1
while a request to apple.com should forward to 8.8.8.8

my dnsmasq file looks as follows:

```
server=/mydomain.local/10.0.1.1
server=/mydomain.local/10.0.1.2
server=/mydomain.local/10.0.1.3
server=/mydomain.local/10.0.1.4

server=/mydomain.com/10.0.1.1
server=/mydomain.com/10.0.1.2
server=/mydomain.com/10.0.1.3
server=/mydomain.com/10.0.1.4

server=8.8.8.8
server=8.8.4.4
listen-address=0.0.0.0
bind-interfaces
```

but the log output is shows that it isn't doing what i'd like:

```
 mypc dnsmasq: query[PTR] 2.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa from 192.168.1.7
 mypc dnsmasq: cached 192.168.1.2 is mypc.mydomain.local
 mypc dnsmasq: query[A] apple.com.mydomain.local from 192.168.1.7
 mypc dnsmasq: forwarded apple.com.mydomain.local to 10.0.1.1
 mypc dnsmasq: forwarded apple.com.mydomain.local to 10.0.1.2
 mypc dnsmasq: forwarded apple.com.mydomain.local to 10.0.1.4
 mypc dnsmasq: forwarded apple.com.mydomain.local to 10.0.1.3
 mypc dnsmasq: reply apple.com.mydomain.local is NXDOMAIN-IPv4
 mypc dnsmasq: query[AAAA] apple.com.mydomain.local from 192.168.1.7
 mypc dnsmasq: forwarded apple.com.mydomain.local to 10.0.1.1
 mypc dnsmasq: forwarded apple.com.mydomain.local to 10.0.1.2
 mypc dnsmasq: forwarded apple.com.mydomain.local to 10.0.1.4
 mypc dnsmasq: forwarded apple.com.mydomain.local to 10.0.1.3
 mypc dnsmasq: reply apple.com.mydomain.local is NXDOMAIN-IPv6
 mypc dnsmasq: query[A] apple.com.mydomain.com from 192.168.1.7
 mypc dnsmasq: forwarded apple.com.mydomain.com to 10.0.1.1
 mypc dnsmasq: forwarded apple.com.mydomain.com to 10.0.1.2
 mypc dnsmasq: forwarded apple.com.mydomain.com to 10.0.1.4
 mypc dnsmasq: forwarded apple.com.mydomain.com to 10.0.1.3
 mypc dnsmasq: reply apple.com.mydomain.com is NXDOMAIN-IPv4
 mypc dnsmasq: query[AAAA] apple.com.mydomain.com from 192.168.1.7
 mypc dnsmasq: forwarded apple.com.mydomain.com to 10.0.1.1
 mypc dnsmasq: forwarded apple.com.mydomain.com to 10.0.1.2
 mypc dnsmasq: forwarded apple.com.mydomain.com to 10.0.1.4
 mypc dnsmasq: forwarded apple.com.mydomain.com to 10.0.1.3
 mypc dnsmasq: reply apple.com.mydomain.com is NXDOMAIN-IPv6
 mypc dnsmasq: query[A] apple.com.dc1.mydomain.com from 192.168.1.7
 mypc dnsmasq: forwarded apple.com.dc1.mydomain.com to 8.8.8.8
 mypc dnsmasq: forwarded apple.com.dc1.mydomain.com to 8.8.4.4
 mypc dnsmasq: forwarded apple.com.dc1.mydomain.com to 10.0.1.1
 mypc dnsmasq: forwarded apple.com.dc1.mydomain.com to 10.0.1.2
 mypc dnsmasq: forwarded apple.com.dc1.mydomain.com to 10.0.1.4
 mypc dnsmasq: forwarded apple.com.dc1.mydomain.com to 10.0.1.3
 mypc dnsmasq: reply apple.com.dc1.mydomain.com is NXDOMAIN-IPv4
 mypc dnsmasq: query[AAAA] apple.com.dc1.mydomain.com from 192.168.1.7
 mypc dnsmasq: forwarded apple.com.dc1.mydomain.com to 8.8.4.4
 mypc dnsmasq: reply apple.com.dc1.mydomain.com is NXDOMAIN-IPv6
 mypc dnsmasq: query[A] apple.com from 192.168.1.7
 mypc dnsmasq: forwarded apple.com to 8.8.4.4
 mypc dnsmasq: reply apple.com is 17.172.224.47
 mypc dnsmasq: reply apple.com is 17.178.96.59
 mypc dnsmasq: reply apple.com is 17.142.160.59
 mypc dnsmasq: query[AAAA] apple.com from 192.168.1.7
 mypc dnsmasq: forwarded apple.com to 8.8.4.4
 mypc dnsmasq: reply apple.com is NODATA-IPv6
```

Thoughts?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: where are those log outputs? I am trying to fix the same thing. I am thinking that I can run dnsmasq on my OWN machine which is accessing a LAN via VPN. Anyting private on the LAN should be redirected to the LAN's DNS, everything else goes upstream to my ISP's DNS.

Comment: These logs are in /var/log/syslog but you have to turn on querry logging in the dnsmasq config